# Can't access "history" in props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have some React component.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Component } from 'react';
import { FormControl, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

type Props = {
  history: any[];
};

// How to define Props only once, in base component

class BaseComponent extends Component<Props, State> { 
}

class HomeComponent extends BaseComponent {

  constructor(props: any) {

    super(props);

    this.state = {
      name: ""
    };
  }

  onSubmit = (event: any) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      this.props.history.push('/messenger'); // TYPE ERROR !!!
  }

  render() {
    <FormControl autoFocus value={this.state.name} />  // TYPE ERROR !!!
    <Button type="submit">Enter</Button>
  }
}
```

When the file with component has extension .js it works fine, but if I rename it to .tsx it gives me the following error.

```
Property 'history' doesn't exist 
on type 'Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<{}>'
```

The same error says that "name" doesn't exist in state. **How to tell React that it's not an error?**

TS config.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "outDir": "output",
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "src"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build",
    "scripts",
    "acceptance-tests",
    "webpack",
    "server"
  ]
}
```

Then I run project this way.

```
react-scripts-ts start
```

**Update #1**

Made it working when I inherit it from React.Component, not sure how to create CustomBaseComponent, but it's probably another question.

```
interface IProps {
  history: any[];
}

class HomeComponent extends React.Component<IProps> {

  public state: any = {};

  constructor(props: IProps) {

    super(props);

    this.state = {
      name: ""
    };

    this.props.history.push('/demo'); // now history works as expected
  }
}
```

**Update #2**

Looks like React prefers inheritance on the HTML component level, rather than standard JS class inheritance.

https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define types for the component's props and state and specify them as type arguments to `Component`:

```
type HomeProps = {
    history: /* insert type here */;
};
type HomeState = {
    name: string;
};

class HomeComponent extends Component<HomeProps, HomeState> {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, one more question, what if I want to create a bse component and inherits everything else from it. How in this case I can define Props and State only once, without adding them to all components? I've updated my example above.

Comment: If I define Props and State in a BaseComponent, it gives me warnings that it is unused variable, and property "history" is still not available in HomeComponent

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with "history".  Can you publish your repository (or a reduced repository that still gives you the problem)?

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/artemiusgreat/examples/src/master/JavaScript/messenger/ there is a folder "src", if I rename any JS file there to TSX file, e.g. HomeComponent, I'm getting the error that history is not available in Props

Comment: Actually, I've already found answer of how to get history after switching from React to React Typescript. I just need to use this.context.history instead of this.props.history. Taken from here https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4059#issuecomment-254437084 at least it doesn't give type error anymore